# Mask secret text password variable in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, masking

I am working on Jenkins.
I have added secret text with Username and Password variable.
I am accessing the password variable using `${password_var1}`.
Currently this prints the password as such in the console output. 
How to mask this Secret text Password variable in the console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mask Password Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) can do that.

Answer (score 0):

try using "Inject passwords to the build as environment variables" from Build Environment. It works.

Comment: An example would be great. I have situation where I use password obtained from user input (interactive) and assign it to a variable and the echo to a file. I used set +x and it hides password on the console output however it shows up in Pipeline Steps.